# Error 404 with a lot of elements

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, dotnetnuke

I am developing a webapplication (HTML-Javascript-C#-DotNetNuke) but I have a problem.

```
$('#myTable').DataTable({
                    ajax: dtBuildAjax('#myTable', '@Url.Content("~/DesktopModules/MVC/XXX/Home/myFunc")',
                        @Dnn.ModuleContext.ModuleId, @Dnn.ModuleContext.TabId,
                        fnInput, fnSuccess
                        ),
                    datatype: 'JSON',
                    type: 'POST',
                    rowCallback: fnRow,
                    columns: [
                        {
                            // First col
                            title: "Title A",
                            data: "first_Arg",
                            ... ... ... ... ... ...
```

The fnInput is a function where I pass the elements to myFunc, in C#, like this:

```
function fnInput() {
    var elemdata = {
        "elem": JSON.stringify(element_app)
    }
    return elemdata;
}
```

myFunc, in C#, is like this:

```
public ActionResult myFunc(string elem) { ...
```

So, if I have 3 elements (like: "1234,0001,9876") for element_app-> no problem.
If I have 350 elements, Chrome-browser says: Error 404

Why?

Comment: Ajax Success was not returned due to an error on the server and there is no ajax error handler. Place a breakpoint in your action before you return the result and check the result object.

Comment: Thanks! I am a newbie! Have you got a snippet, please?

Comment: There is no snippet, place a breakpoint in your action and further up the stack in your code behind to ensure all your code works as expected on the backend and contains the expected results before returning them from the action.

Comment: Ok, I don't see errors. URI seems ok for 3 or 350 elements. 
But, for 350-elemts-URI I see Error 404.

Comment: Are your elements posted in the URL string during the post?  If so you might be having issues with the max length of the URL on a browser and not the complete URL is sent, causing the FileNotFound error.

Comment: Yes! My URI is like this: alfa.localhost/xxx/yyy/zzz?element=...
Have a suggestion? Thanks a lot for your important help!

Comment: See the Examples in the DataTable Documentation on [**ajax data**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data)

Comment: Nope, I haven't find a solution

Comment: Hi, I try to send post-request but, in Chrome-console I see an URI like: website+data.
I don't know if I have an error (but, where?) or the browser cuts my URI but I don't see the "short-URI"